# Parallel task execution order

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have the following code:

```
public IEnumerable<Task> ExecuteJobs(Action[] pJobsToExecute)
{
    var tasks = new Task[pJobsToExecute.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < pJobsToExecute.Length; i++)
    {
        //tasks[i] = new Task((index) => ProcessJob(pJobsToExecute[(int)index], (int)index), i);
        //tasks[i].Start();
        tasks[i] = new Task(() => ProcessJob(pJobsToExecute[i], i));
        tasks[i].Start();
    }

    return tasks;
}

public void ProcessJob(Action jobToProcess, int index)
{
    // ...
}
```

I need to log the order of the tasks being sent to the ProcessJob method, I use the index parameter for this. But this code:

```
tasks[i] = new Task(() => ProcessJob(jobs[i], i));
tasks[i].Start();
```

Will not give the correct order in which the actions will be executed. This code will give the correct order:

```
tasks[i] = new Task((index) => ProcessJob(pJobsToExecute[(int)index], (int)index), i);
tasks[i].Start();
```

I don't understand why this overload for Task fixes the issue. Does the i get passed to the index parameter based on actual order of execution? Or have my tests been incorrect and will this code also fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating closure over the loop variable `i` and using its value later on, after the loop has progressed.

When creating a lambda function with `() => ProcessJob(jobs[i], i)` the compiler creates a hidden reference to the variable `i` which is updated by the `for` loop. The same reference is read when `ProcessJob` is called as part of the task being executed.

The behavior you see is the result of a race condition: even though you are starting the tasks *inside* the loop, those tasks run on separate threads and the threads do not start executing immediately. When they *do* start the value of `i` has been modified (because more iterations of the loop have been completed) and the value read by `ProcessJob` is "wrong".

The version with the `index` variable creates a *local copy* of `i` which is logically separate from it and is not modified together with `i`; this copy is therefore immune to being changed before the task has a chance to start. You would get the same (correct) behavior with:

```
var index = i;
// Note that tasks[index] can also be tasks[i] -- it makes no difference
// because that value is used strictly during the current loop iteration
tasks[index] = new Task(() => ProcessJob(pJobsToExecute[index], index));
tasks[index].Start();
```

Creating a local copy of captured variables as above is the solution to all problems of this type.